# Visual Studio Deployment Project: Allow User to Select Configuration file at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, installation

I have a Windows service I built with VS2008. The service is installed on the target machine via and MSI, which I built using a Setup and Deployment project in Visual Studio. When the MSI is run, it copies the binaries needed to the target directory and installs the service in the service control manager.

I have the projects set up so that they create a "Configs" directory in the target directory. There is one configuration file for each type of environment (Dev, QA, Prod).

As it currently stands, when the installation is complete, the user must go to the Configs directory and copy the desired configuration to the base target directory. This is a source of confusion and a few errors.

I would like the MSI file to prompt the user for the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've accomplished the same need functionality in setup projects for my service deployments successfully.

First, you'll need add your "Configs" directory under the Application Folder in "File System" of your setup project.

Second, view the "User Interface" designer. Here you will need to add a new dialog. What I did was add a dialog with two radio buttons (choices being development or production). I placed mine after the "Welcome" dialog in the setup menu sequence.

Select your new dialog and add what you need in the Properties window. In my body text, I tell the user to "Select a deployment option". From there you set values for each choice. My `Button1Label` property reads as "Development" with a `Button1Value` of 1. Button 2 is "Production" with a value of 2. I named the `ButtonProperty` "DEPLOY".

Finally, add each config file to the File System under "Application Folder" -> "Configs".
The key action here is tying each config file to a deployment option. For a development config file it's `Condition` property would be:

```
DEPLOY=1
```

Similarily the production config `Condition` property would be:

```
DEPLOY=2
```

It's simple but it does exactly what you need it to do. Which is hard to do with setup projects. They lack a whole lot of functionality.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar right around the time you posted this solution. I added a radio button custom ui, then added a custom action that I run on install. It gets the value of the selected radio button passed to it and copies the proper configuration files as needed. Very similar solution to yours. Mine seems like more work, but both get it done.